# Send Order Confirmation automatically to customer's mobile number

Tags: api

I'm trying to implement below SMS API from Textlocal.in which I have received.
I want to send automatic order confirmation text message to customers placing an order on this website. http://52.77.236.176/

```
    <?php
    // Textlocal account details
    $username = 'youremail@address.com';
    $hash = 'Your API hash';

    // Message details
    $numbers = array(918123456789, 918987654321);
    $sender = urlencode('TXTLCL');
    $message = rawurlencode('This is your message');

    $numbers = implode(',', $numbers);

    // Prepare data for POST request
    $data = array('username' => $username, 'hash' => $hash, 'numbers' => $numbers, "sender" => $sender, "message" => $message);

    // Send the POST request with cURL
    $ch = curl_init('http://api.textlocal.in/send/');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    // Process your response here
    echo $response;
?>
```

Now I'm Confused about where i will have to place this code in wordpress. I mean on which page ?

Answer (score 0):

This is an e-commerce plugin called Woocommerce, you need to read up on their hooks, such as `woocommerce_new_order` [here](http://hookr.io/actions/woocommerce_new_order/). The code you pasted would usually go inside the active theme's `functions.php`. All the themes are located in `wp-content/themes`, you can easily check which theme is active in the admin dashboard under *Appearance -> Themes* in the left-side menu.

Comment: Perfect, Thank you ! So I will put this code inside current activated theme's  functions.php page. few more questions arises , i get that order id right? which you have mentioned. how do i get the number from the page where user will input ?